# Calculate sum for items in nested jsonb array

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, sum, jsonb

So I have Postgres DB table 'purchases' with columns 'id' and 'receipt'. 'id' is primary int column, the value in column 'receipt' is jsonb and can look like this:

```
{
  "shop_name":"some_shop_name", 
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "foo", 
      "spent": 49,
      "quantity": 1
    },     
    {
      "name": "bar", 
      "price": 99,
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "abc", 
      "price": 999,
      "quantity": 1
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

There can be varied amount of items in receipt.

In the end I need to write a query so the resulting table contains purchase id and amount spent on all **bar** for every purchase in table as such:

| id | spent |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 198 |
| .. | ... |

My issue:

I can't figure out how to work with jsonb inside select query along regular columns in the resulting table, I guess query should be structured as this:

```
SELECT p.id, %jsonb_parsing_result_here% AS spent
FROM purchases p
```

It's blocking me from moving further with iterating through items in FOR cycle (or maybe using another way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unnest the `items` from the `receipt` column with a lateral join and the `jsonb_array_elements` function like:

```
SELECT p.id, SUM((item->>'price')::NUMERIC)
FROM purchases p,
LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(p.receipt->'items') r (item)
GROUP BY p.id
```

It's also possible to add a where condition, for example:

```
WHERE item->>'name' = 'bar
```